# Wiring Question When attempting to Replace Honeywell with a Nest Thermostat

Tags: nest

I am trying to determine which Nest will work to replace honeywell device. I am a bit confused with the current wires. At the moment I have; G=Green Wire, R=Red Wire, O= Blue Wire, Y=Yellow Wire. It looks like there is a jumper on R and RC, and an unknown wire is running from Y into W.   Would any of you have had a similar experience and would know  which Nest will work for me? Thanks in advance. (See attached)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the furnace/air-handler end please?